# Javascript loop for pathfinding clearance

Tags: javascript, loops, path-finding, a-star

I'm trying to add a clearance calculation on a pathfinding script (javascript).

I really don't know how to achieve this programmatically...

I'm using an AStar script, so I have a double-dimensionnal array with tiles like this :

```
[
    [0,0,0,0,0,1],
    [0,1,0,1,1,1],
    [0,1,1,1,0,1],
    [1,1,1,0,0,1],
    [1,1,0,1,0,1],
    [1,0,0,0,0,1]
]
```

Here, 0 means "wall", and 1 means "path".
1 is the default clearance.

How to loop over each tile (calculation from top-left to bottom-right) to have the max clearance of it, like in this scheme :

https://aigamedev.com/open/tutorials/clearance-based-pathfinding/#TheTrueClearanceMetric

The only problem is the "loop-format", where I need to test if the current tile is 0 or 1, to store the max clearance

Many thanks !

**EDIT**

For those who can't see the website, some schemes of what I mean :

*Steps to calcul clearance*

[image: Steps to calcul clearance]

*Example of a full result*

[image: Example of a full result]

Comment: I cannot access that site. It looks like a nested pair of for-loops should be enough though? What have you done so far?

Comment: Strange, this site works well (found on Google, I'm not the owner). I have nothing to give you, I try some loops in loops in loops... but that's a brain-break for me :/ I'm not sure the AStar code I'm using could be useful.. I'll post an image of what I'm trying to achieve :)

Comment: How long have you been working on this? It could take days or weeks, but I would suggest you to keep trying to solve it yourself. It's surely non trivial, but it doesn't seem impossible either and you will gain lot of knowledge from your work.

Comment: Well, I find a way to do this : https://jsfiddle.net/uctsf755/ But is there a more optimized way ? For example, each diagonal is tested twice...

Comment: still a bit confused what the numbers are supposed to mean? it looks like manhattan distance from nearest wall but there are '3's right next to some walls

Comment: in terms of complexity, n^2 squares and you need a for loop to look up and left of each square, o(n^3) seems to be as optimal as it gets. your code is o(n^3) so i think any faster calculation will also be in the region of o(n^3)

Comment: @softwarenewbie7331 I don't understand ; As you can see in the (d) image, the tile is fixed at '3' because it encouters a wall on (3, 1) (and more under)

Answer (score 0):

You will still need the outer set of nested for loops to go through each square as in your [jsfiddle.net/uctsf755](http://%20jsfiddle.net/uctsf755) code but within each square you want to do Breadth First Search to locate the closest wall. once you find one you can actually update all the squares you have looked at along the way, since the closest wall to those square will be the same wall. Remember which ones you have visited so you don't have to do bfs on them again.

Total complexity will be around O(n^2) since you should only visit each square once.

Good Luck!